# 'Unknown error' on login with default FBA setup, an iisreset fixes for ~24hr

Tags: wss-3.0, forms-authentication

I have a basic WSS 3.0 site set up with an ASP.NET membership database and default forms login. There is no custom code or any customization on the entire site.

When I try to log in, I get 'unknown error', regardless of whether username/pass is correct or not. An iisreset fixes this for the rest of the day. When I check the site again in the morning, same unknown error.

Only error in /12/logs:

> 01/11/2010 12:00:39.11    w3wp.exe
>   (0x02FC)
>     0x0D58 Windows SharePoint Services
>     General
>     8dzz High     Exception Type:
>   System.ArgumentNullException 
>   Exception Message: Value cannot be
>   null.  Parameter name: value

**EDIT:** Here's my membership/role providers in web.config:

```
  <membership defaultProvider="FormsMember">
    <providers>
      <add
        connectionStringName="ConnectionString"
        enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
        enablePasswordReset="true"
        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
        applicationName="/"
        requiresUniqueEmail="false"
        passwordFormat="Hashed"
        maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
        minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
        minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
        passwordAttemptWindow="10"
        passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
        name="FormsMember"
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider,System.Web,Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </providers>
  </membership>

  <!-- role provider -->
  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="FBARole">
    <providers>
      <add
        connectionStringName="ConnectionString"
        applicationName="/"
        name="FBARole"
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider,System.Web,Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
```

**EDIT 2:**

After making the suggested changes to web.config to view the error, here's what the site now says once the login fails:

> Value cannot be null.  Parameter name:
>   value   at
>   System.String.EndsWith(String value,
>   StringComparison comparisonType)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PostAuthenticateRequestHandler(Object
>   oSender, EventArgs ea)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

**EDIT 3:**

I am still having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

what exactly do you mean with "default forms login". What role provider and/or membership provider are you using?

When debugging this issue also check event for errors after doing a login.

If your FBA is using SQL server, also check the SQL logs.

Also i can warmly recommend using SQL Profiler to see whats actually fetched from SQL server when doing a login.

hth
Anders Rask

Answer (score 0):

Is there some kind of job that runs overnight, or is the web app set to recycle once per day?

Comment: yeah, app pool recycles every night, but that's default for all ..

Comment: no job running at night.  this site is as OOB as it gets

Comment: @next_connect: Could you please make this a comment as it isn't an answer, rather a request for more information. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Find and set CallStack="true", CustomErrors="Off," debug="true" in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468921/sharepoint-unknown-error-debugging-but-cant-turn-on-callstack) (You will probably have to edit the web.config that is in your LAYOUTS folder, since that is where I expect your logon page to reside) so that - instead of getting unkown error - you will hopefully get a more meaningful error + stacktrace. The stacktrace is what we are after. Please post it here.

Comment: thanks, i made these changes.
unfortunately, we will have to wait until tomorrow since changing web.config does an automatic IISreset which solves the problem for a day

Comment: It actually performs an application pool recycle, which is similar to an iisreset, but not quite the same. Looking forward to tomorrow :D

Comment: hi,
i have posted the new error

Answer (score 0):

How have the FB settings been applied via a SPWebConfigModification object? Just wondering if the farm is updating your web config settings which is messing things up.

Comment: i have done nothing with this

Comment: @Simon: The 'add comment' feature on the question is the best place to ask for more information. Otherwise the question gets cluttered with answers that aren't really answers. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex - sure - cheers for feedback.